# What is the fastest way to perform this change?

Tags: macro, repeated-commands, performance

In my codes, I often have to do this kind of text editing:

```
u(:,:,:) = 0._dp
v(:,:,:) = 0._dp
temp(:,:,:) = 0._dp
```

To:

```
grid%u(0:nx,0:ny,0:nz) = 0._dp
grid%v(0:nx,0:ny,0:nz) = 0._dp
grid%temp(0:nx,0:ny,0:nz) = 0._dp
```

I'm using the record option, which is something that I recently learned how to use and therefore not excel at. Here is how I do it (cursor is placed on "u").

1. `qq` / `i grid%` / `ESC`  (start recording and store in buffer "q", go to insert mode and enter "grid%", escape insert mode)
2. `f:` / `i 0` / `ESC` / `;;` / `.` / `;;` / `.` (go to next ":", insert 0, escape insert mode, go to 2nd next ":", repeat last command, go to 2nd next ":", repeat last command)
3. `;` / `a nz` / `ESC` / `,,` / `a ny` / `ESC` / `,,` / `a nx` / `ESC` (go to next ":", insert after cursor "nz", escape insert mode, go to 2nd previous ":", insert after cursor "ny", escape insert mode, go to 2nd previous ":", insert after cursor "nz", escape insert mode)
4. `j` / `SHIFT-^` / `@q` (go down one line, go to first non-blank character, apply macro "q")
5. `j` / `SHIFT-^` / `@q` (go down one line, go to first non-blank character, apply macro "q")

The only thing I can think of which can make this code editing more efficient is to use the macro on the two lines in one command. Intuitively, I tried `2@q` but that did not work.

Comment: You could visually select your lines and type `:'<,'>norm @q`. The macro `q` should be applied once per line. You won't have to insert the visual range `'<,'>`, Vim will do it automatically for you. So, you will only have to type `:norm @q`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your recording doesn't include any vertical motion. This means that `2@q` will play your recording twice on the same line.

You could add a `j` at the end of your macro to move down.

Or you could use `2:norm @q` to play your recording on the current line and the following one.

The "count" you give to Vim before running an ex command is transformed into a range. Here, your `2` is transformed into `.,.+1` which covers the current line (`.`) and the one below (`.+1`).

Comment: If I do that, it inserts `grid%` before the tab so I end up with `grid%<tab>u(0:`...

Comment: @solalito When your begin the recording of your macro, hit `_` or `^` to make sure that each time the macro will be replayed it will begin on the first non whitespace of the line.

Comment: That's because you use `i` instead of `I`: `qqIgrid%…`